# Accidentally created additional folder while trying to extend swap memory in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, swap

I have little to zero knowledge about Ubuntu and only have recently installed it on my laptop. I wanted to extend the swap memory so i followed the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04 . In the process, I accidentally created an unnecessary folder that takes a whopping 13gigs of storage. I want to delete the
"swa[fo" https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGPky.png
directory from my device. Thank you.

Comment: Please copy the text instead of adding image to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the name of the file in single quotes:

```
rm 'swa[fo'
```

or escape the square bracket

```
rm swa\[fo
```

P.S. And IMHO this is a file, not a directory. You can check with above command using `ls -l` instead of `rm`. If it is really directory use `rm -r` instead of `rm`